# Can't logged in after fetching data with redux

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

So, I (finally) can fetching data from jsonplaceholder using redux only. The problem is, my login won't let me logged in, saying "user not found". Before using redux, it works well. Please take a minute to see my code (and help me):

**body.js**

```js
import React, {Component} from "react";
import "./style.css";
import { Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom"
import {About, Login, Register} from "../../pages"
import { connect } from "react-redux";

class Body extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            userData: [],
            admin: [{
                name: "admin",
                role: "adm",
                email: "adm@adm.com",
                username: "admin",
                password: "123"
            }]
        }
    }

    componentDidMount = () => {
        fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => {
                const dataUser = data.map(user =>({
                    ...user,
                    password: "pass",
                    role: "user",
                }));

                this.props.doFetch({ 
                    userData: [...this.state.admin, ...dataUser]
                })
            })
    }

    showPage = () => {
        return (
            <Switch>
            <Route path="/about"  children={(props) => <About {...props} listUsers={this.state.userData} />} />
                <Route path="/login">
                    <Login />
                </Route>
                <Route path="/register">
                    <Register listUsers={this.state.userData} tambahUser={this.addUsers} />
                </Route>
            </Switch>
        )
    }

    render() { 
        return (
            <>
                {
                    this.showPage()
                }
            </>
        );
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    userList: state.data.userData
})

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
    doFetch: (userData) => dispatch({ type: "FETCH", payload: userData })
})
 
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Body);
```

**login.js**

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { RowInput, Button } from '../../components';
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { Redirect } from "react-router-dom"

class Login extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            username: "",
            password: "",
        }
    }

    onChangeInput = e => {
        this.setState({
            [e.target.name]: e.target.value
        })
    }

    onLogin = async () => {
        const { username, password } = this.state

        const exist = this.props.userList.find(user => user.username === username && user.password === password)
        if (exist) {
            alert(`Welcome ${username}`) 
            this.props.doLogin(username, password)
        } else alert("User not found.")


    }

    render() { 
        if (this.props.statusLogin){
            return <Redirect to="/about" />
        }

        return (
            <div className="login">
                <form className="login-form" method="POST">
                    <div className="container-log">
                        <h1 className="judul">Login</h1>
                        <RowInput value={this.state.username} label="Username" placeholder="Username" type="text" name="username" onChange={this.onChangeInput}/>
                        <RowInput value={this.state.password} label="Password" placeholder="Password" type="password" name="password" onChange={this.onChangeInput}/>
                        <Button onClickInput={this.onLogin}>Masuk</Button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    statusLogin: state.auth.isLoggedIn,
    usernameLogin: state.auth.username,
    userList: state.data.userData
})

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
    doLogin: (users) => dispatch({ type: "LOGIN", payload: {username: users} })
})
 
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Login)
```

**getdata.js**

```js
const initialState = {
    userData: []
}

const dataReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    console.log("state: ", state);
    console.log("action: ", action);

    switch (action.type) {
        case "FETCH":
            return {
                userData: [action.payload.userData]
            }
        default:
            return state
    }
}

export default dataReducer
```

Console log:
[image]
The array has been stored................right?

I'm seriously have no idea why my login not work? Is there something on my code that make it not work? Thank you before!

Comment: Based on the provided code you don't process `LOGIN` action in reducer.

Comment: @KenBekov no, i provide it. just in different file. is that affected the program?

Comment: @KenBekov I've tried to make it in same file, but it's no use. I still cant logged in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after three hours searching and trying, I only need to comment/delete function `mapStateToProps` in `body.js`. I assume it's because I'm calling and store data at the same time? Idk for sure either, so, if anyone know the exactly why, feel free to correct me. Thankies. Have a good day, everyone!